# Need help in CSS and jquery offset

Tags: jquery, css

i have an issue in the offset, it returns the same top offset for all the targeted elements in my document.

I have the elements positioned relatively to each other, and it returns something like this for the 4 elements

```
Object {top: 702.109375, left: 331.19189453125}
Object {top: 702.109375, left: 494.31884765625}
Object {top: 702.109375, left: 681.9716796875}
Object {top: 702.109375, left: 910.89697265625}
```

CSS code for the elemets

```
div[class^='image-'] {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 100%;
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="image-1" id="features"></div>
<div class="image-2" id="tech"></div>
<div class="image-3" id="pricing"></div>
<div class="image-4" id="gallary"></div>
```

JS code

```
$(".top-image-link .page").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var position = $("#"+id).offset();
    console.log($("#"+id).css("top"));
    var top = position.left;
    $(document).scrollTop(top+"px");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: top
    }, 2000);
    console.log(position);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Please post your HTML, CSS and Javascript - enough to reproduce the issue. Otherwise there is no way we can help you.

Comment: Did you try .position() instead, and if not try adding the value of .css('top') to your element.  Either that or your targeted items may be changed after being measured?  Without html/script its a guessing game

Comment: @Rhumborl thanks for your help i have posted the code

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond thanks for replying yes i have tried the position and still returns the same thing

Comment: `var top = position.left;` should be `var top = position.top;`?

Comment: there is no `class=page` in your html or css. Provide enough to replicate the problem. A demo in jsfiddle.net would also be helpful

Comment: @charlietfl i target all the classes starts with image-, and it works with jsfiddle just fine i guess the issue just like MiltoxBeyond said something is changing their positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for helping but i found the answer, the issue was the first letter was cap in the link that connects to the element *internally screaming*